# Correctly hiding material checkboxes

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, angular-material, angular7

I've got angular material checkboxes that I managed to hide. Now that the checkboxes are hidden, I want to be able to select the image and have a CSS border-bottom for each image selected. So far, I was able to select a single image which isn't what I want.

How can multiple images be selected instead of one at a time? The below code is what I've written so far.

-TypeScript

```
       <div *ngFor="let image of images; let i = index" style="display: inline !important;">
          <mat-checkbox (change)="SelectedImages($event)" [value]="image.imageName">
            <img style="width: 60px; padding-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;"                            
              src="assets/imageFolder/{{ image.imageName }}.png" [ngStyle]="{'border-bottom': checkedBoxes(image.imageName)}">
          </mat-checkbox>
       </div>       
    </form>

    checkedBoxes(imageName) {
            if (this.selectedCheckBoxes === imageName) {
                return '3px solid red';
                } else {
                return 'none';
                 }


    SelectedImages($event) {
        const imagesFormGroup = <FormArray>this.imageFormGroup.get('images') as FormArray;
        this.imageValue = imagesFormGroup.value;    
        this.selectedCheckBoxes = $event.source.value;                  
                    }
```

-CSS

```
::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-inner-container {
display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: I would not use checkboxes for such a thing. I would build a map of images that are selected, adding and removing them on click, and change my condition to `this.selectedImages[imageName] != undefined` or similar.

Comment: Thank you for your response @BrettJeffreson. How would that look like?